How to dynamically create and manage multiple popup dialogs in Angular?
I am working on an Angular(17.x) project where I need to create and manage multiple popup dialogs dynamically. I aim to avoid manually creating separate components, inputs, and outputs for each popup. Instead, I want to use a service to create these dialogs and handle their events dynamically.
I have tried to implement a solution using ViewContainerRef and a custom service to open dialogs. However, the dialogs are not opening as expected, and I am encountering issues with binding inputs and outputs dynamically. Below is my current implementation.
Html file
<button (click)="popupAOpen()">Open Popup A</button>
<button (click)="popupBOpen()">Open Popup B</button>
<button (click)="popupCOpen()">Open Popup C</button>
<ng-template #dialogContainer></ng-template>

component typescript file
import { Component, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { PopupWindowService } from './popup-window.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-page',
  templateUrl: './my-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-page.component.css']
})
export class MyPage{
  @ViewChild('dialogContainer', { read: ViewContainerRef }) viewContainerRef!: ViewContainerRef;
  
  inputA1: any = 'exampleA1';
  inputA2: any = 'exampleA2';
  inputB1: any = 'exampleB1';
  inputB2: any = 'exampleB2';
  inputC1: any = 'exampleC1';
  inputC2: any = 'exampleC2';

  constructor(private dialogService: PopupWindowService) {}

  popupAOpen() {
    this.dialogService.openDialog(
      this.viewContainerRef,
      PopUpA,
      { isVisible: true, inputA1: this.inputA1, inputA2: this.inputA2 },
      { outputA1: this.outputA1.bind(this), outputA2: this.outputA2.bind(this) }
    );
  }

  popupBOpen() {
    this.dialogService.openDialog(
      this.viewContainerRef,
      PopUpB,
      { isVisible: true, inputB1: this.inputB1, inputB2: this.inputB2 },
      { outputB1: this.outputB1.bind(this), outputB2: this.outputB2.bind(this) }
    );
  }

  popupCOpen() {
    this.dialogService.openDialog(
      this.viewContainerRef,
      PopUpC,
      { isVisible: true, inputC1: this.inputC1, inputC2: this.inputC2 },
      { outputC1: this.outputC1.bind(this), outputC2: this.outputC2.bind(this) }
    );
  }

  outputA1() { /* Handle outputA1 */ }
  outputA2() { /* Handle outputA2 */ }
  outputB1() { /* Handle outputB1 */ }
  outputB2() { /* Handle outputB2 */ }
  outputC1() { /* Handle outputC1 */ }
  outputC2() { /* Handle outputC2 */ }
}

PopupWindowService
import { Injectable, ComponentRef, ApplicationRef, Injector, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PopupWindowService {
  private dialogRefs: ComponentRef<any>[] = [];

  constructor(
    private appRef: ApplicationRef,
    private injector: Injector
  ) {}

  openDialog(viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef, component: any, inputs: any, outputs: any = {}): ComponentRef<any> {
    const contentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(component, { injector: this.injector });
    
    Object.keys(inputs).forEach(inputName => {
      contentRef.instance[inputName] = inputs[inputName];
    });

    const dialogRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(DialogComponent, { injector: this.injector });
    dialogRef.instance.content = contentRef.location.nativeElement;
    this.appRef.attachView(dialogRef.hostView);
    this.appRef.attachView(contentRef.hostView);

    document.body.appendChild((dialogRef.hostView as any).rootNodes[0] as HTMLElement);
    this.dialogRefs.push(dialogRef);

    Object.keys(outputs).forEach(outputName => {
      if (contentRef.instance[outputName]) {
        contentRef.instance[outputName].subscribe(outputs[outputName]);
      }
    });

    dialogRef.instance.show();
    contentRef.instance.closeDialog.subscribe(() => this.closeDialog(dialogRef, contentRef));

    return dialogRef;
  }

  closeDialog(dialogRef: ComponentRef<any>, contentRef: ComponentRef<any>) {
    dialogRef.instance.hide();
    this.appRef.detachView(dialogRef.hostView);
    this.appRef.detachView(contentRef.hostView);
    dialogRef.destroy();
    contentRef.destroy();
    this.dialogRefs = this.dialogRefs.filter(ref => ref !== dialogRef);
  }
}

I have attempted to dynamically create and manage popups using a service, but the dialogs are not opening correctly. I suspect there might be an issue with how I am binding inputs and outputs dynamically.
Specific Questions

How can I correctly bind inputs and outputs dynamically to the popup
components?
Are there any improvements or alternatives to dynamically manage multiple popups in Angular?

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!

please share the contents of dialog component, is it possible to share a stackblitz with the issue replicated

ok i will share

here is a stackblitz to help you replicate stackblitz

Wouldn't it be easier to pass data to and from the dialog using the service directly? Creating some subject/observable combo, which can handle input and some sort of an action method, to handle output.
